# How to convert PY to EXE but only specify module

Tags: python, python-3.x, auto-py-to-exe

I need some help to convert my Python app to an exe executable file.

But when I list all the files in the output folder, it shows all my installed Python modules, not only the imported ones, so how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a virtual environment and `pip install` only the required modules. This is more of a workaround rather than an actual solution.

Comment: How I can download virtual environment?

Comment: I believe that the venv module is installed by default. Open a terminal window and type ```python -m venv``` followed by the path to where you want it to be. I would recommend googling how to create and access venv, becuase how you activate it depends on your OS. (Note: if that doesn't work, maybe try python3 instead of just python)

Comment: If you are using PyInstaller, you can also add the --onefile option to only get a single .exe